# NuGet execution policy errors when installing MvcScaffolding package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, nuget, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2010, Windows XP, and using ASP.NET MVC4 RC in a project. I have NuGet v2.0.30619.9119 installed.

I'm now trying to install the MvcScaffolding package via NuGet Package Manager Console. I get the following errors:

```
PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.1.10311.0)'.
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=224682. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 4.1.10715.0'.
Successfully installed 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.6'.
File Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\init.ps
1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  'Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\init.ps1' $__rootPath $__toolsPath $__package $__project
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Successfully installed 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.7'.
File Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\init.
ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  'Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\init.ps1' $__rootPath $__toolsPath $__package $__project
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Successfully added 'EntityFramework 4.1.10715.0' to MyProject.Web.
Successfully added 'T4Scaffolding 1.0.6' to MyProject.Web.
File Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\install.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\inst
all.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  'Y:\asp\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.6\tools\install.ps1' $__rootPath $__toolsPath $__package $__project
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

'InstallationDummyFile.txt' already exists. Skipping...
Successfully added 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.7' to MyProject.Web.
File Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\install.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\in
stall.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  'Y:\asp\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.7\tools\install.ps1' $__rootPath $__toolsPath $__package $__project
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Because the init scripts aren't being executed after the install, the MvcScaffolding package is not installed correctly and the `scaffold` command is not recognised.

I don't know what to do about these code signing issues. Here are the current security settings:

```
PM> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
Scope           ExecutionPolicy
-----           ---------------
MachinePolicy   Undefined
UserPolicy      Undefined
Process         RemoteSigned
CurrentUser     Undefined
LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

Can I change the Process scope to be Unrestricted?  If so, how? Running `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in the NuGet console does not work:

```
PM> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):Y
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will
 retain its current effective execution policy of "RemoteSigned". Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information, please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPol
icy."
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  Unrestricted
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

I've also tried doing all of this as an Administrator and that didn't help either.

Any advice or ideas would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I can set the process execution policy in NuGet like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

But when I restart Visual Web Developer, the setting is forgotten and I still get an error as it keeps trying to execute the `init.psl` files

How can I change the execution policy permanently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I have MvcScaffolding installed correctly now.

I had to first bypass all security in NuGet:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

But when I restart Visual Web Developer I still get those same PowerShell errors todo with the NuGet running `init.pls` on startup.

I've worked out that it's because I was storing my project on a network drive. Apparently PowerShell won't execute scripts from the network drive by default.

I tried using CasPol to change the security settings, but couldn't get it to work. I gave up when I saw other people couldn't get VS to work with mapped drives as well:

[CAS not working for VS2010 mapped drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171176/cas-not-working-for-vs2010-mapped-drive/7444666#7444666)

Anyway, I just have my project local now, and MvcScaffolding is installed and working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the policy for user scope and using a more secure policy like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Requires that all scripts and configuration files be signed by a trusted publisher, including scripts that you write on the local computer.
Prompts you before running scripts from publishers that you have not yet classified as trusted or untrusted.

For exemple, installing a EntityFramework ask permission to run the script:

```
Executing script file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\zzz\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'
Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File C:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\zzz\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1 is published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"):R
```